# ¿Por qué llamamos "paraguayo" a esta fruta?

Tags: etimología, españa, comida

A la fruta de la fotografía la llamamos "paraguayo", por lo menos en la zona donde yo vivo.

[image]

Esta acepción aparece en el [diccionario de la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Rqd7NAW), pero no he encontrado nada sobre su origen. ¿Esta fruta tiene algo que ver con Paraguay? ¿Alguien sabe alguna cosa sobre la etimología del término "paraguayo" para denominar a esta fruta?

Comment: Cuando dices "en la zona donde yo vivo", ¿te refieres a Barcelona o a España? Aquí en Andalucía también se la conoce como "paraguayo". Interesante pregunta, por cierto. Y más interesante que el diccionario diga que su nombre en realidad es "paraguaya", en femenino.

Comment: Parece algo propio de España, pues como se indica en el artículo [Prunus persica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_persica): _Las variedades cuyos frutos tienen forma achatada se suelen denominar en España 'paraguayas', 'paraguayos' o 'chatos'_

Comment: @Charlie: He puesto "zona" precisamente porque no estaba del todo segura de la extensión del área geográfica donde se usa este vocablo con este significado. Pero imagino que, por lo que dice la RAE, no se trata sólo de Barcelona.

Comment: Curiosamente, en el dialecto balear del catalán se le llama _xino_, que coincide más con [su origen](http://www.agrumingenieria.es/index.php/noticias/35-dos-frutales-de-moda-paraguayo-y-platarina): 
_El Paraguayo es una variedad de melocotón, procedente de una mutación relativamente actual de éste, que procede de China_

Comment: "**Saturn peaches** (also known as **doughnut peach** or **flat peach**), are a variety of peach...". Los ingleses nos dan mil vueltas a la hora de poner nombres a las cosas.

Comment: @Charlie: Por lo menos se entiende el por qué de todos esos términos. Hace muy poco que he descubierto que [en italiano se les llama "tabacchiere"](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/9815/707), pero tampoco tengo claro su origen y por eso he hecho una pregunta en Italian.SE.

Comment: Quiero agregar más misterio que aclaración. Soy de Paraguay, y aquí NO existe esa fruta, ni en forma silvestre ni en cultivos comerciales.

Answer (score 4):

La primera entrada de *paraguaya* con tal definición aparece en 1936. Nótese que especifica que se usa esta palabra en *América*<sup>1</sup>:

> **Paraguaya.** f. *Amér.* Fruta de hueso semejante al pérsico y de sabor también parecido, de forma aplastada y de mucho consumo en Europa.
>
> - *Diccionario de la lengua española* (1936)

*Paraguayo* lleva otra significación más antigua<sup>2</sup> en Bolivia:

> **paraguayo.**
>
> **I.   1.**    m. *Bo:E.* Rosquete hecho de azúcar, almidón y clavo de olor.
>
> - [*Diccionario de americanismos*](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=paraguayo) (2010)

En inglés los paraguayos (la fruta) son también conocidos como ["doughnut peach"](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2009/jul/15/doughnut-peach).

Dado todo esto, me parece probable que tome su nombre de los rosquetes por su forma similar ("doughnut-shaped"), como ha pasado en inglés.

[image]

---

---

**Notas:**

<sup>**1.** De hecho, esta fruta solía llamarse por otro nombre en España:</sup>

> <sup>— *melocotón tomatero* o *paraguayo*: es «chato y chafado», la *piel* rojiza
> y la *carne* blanca. Con este nombre se designa la variedad de carne
> blanca llamada paraguayo; esta denominación es de reciente introducción,
> pues para los mayores el único nombre conocido es el de *melocotón
> tomatero.*</sup>
>
> <sup>• [*Denominaciones populares de las especies frutales en Alfaro (La Rioja)*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4bds8iUZv7cC&dq=%22paraguayo%22) (1997)</sup>

<sup>**2.** La primera entrada de *paraguayo* con la definición de una especie de rosquete antecede a la de la fruta por dos décadas:</sup>

> <sup>**PARAGUAYO, YA** ... || *Amér.* En Bolivia, rosquete de azúcar y almidón.</sup>
>
> <sup>• *Diccionario de la lengua española*, Alemany y Bolufer (1917)</sup>

<sup>**3.** No eres la primera en preguntarse esto:</sup>

> <sup>Se llama, "La Paraguaya". La denominación nos sorprendió y, lógico, inmediatamente indagamos su genealogía, su procedencia. "La Paraguaya" es una especie de melocotón, de la familia del durazno. Petiza.  Jugosa. Riquísima. Pero, de dónde venía su nombre? Era un misterio que nos intrigó y nos lanzó en pos de su revelación. Nadie, entre nuestras amistades, escapó de la indagación, del interrogatorio. Todos sin embargo estuvieron contestes en acusar la más sorprendente ignorancia. Por ello, el enigma se mantuvo.</sup>
>
> <sup>Como tantas cosas populares, "La Paraguaya" tiene también el origen de su apelativo perdido en la noche inmemorial. Puede haber llegado a España acompañando el regreso de los viejos señores de la aventura o con algún indiano reintegrado al solar patricio. O tal vez, nació en la trama desconocida y romancesca de...</sup>
>
> <sup>• [*Por los caminos del viejo mundo: visión de un periodista paraguayo*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UMsQAQAAIAAJ), Sindulfo Martínez (1964)</sup>

Comment: ¿Cuál es la fuente de la primera cita? ¿Qué diccionario es?

Comment: @Charo la edición 1936 del *Diccionario de la lengua española* de la RAE (el volumen *Usual* es en contraste con el *Manual* y el *Suplemento*). Puedes buscarlo aquí: http://buscon.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle

Comment: Me parece una hipótesis totalmente razonable.

Comment: De hecho, en el [artículo de Wikipedia sobre Gastronomía de Bolivia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastronom%C3%ADa_de_Bolivia) aparecen las "roscas paraguayas".

Answer (score 1):

El paraguayo es *[Prunus persica var. platycarpa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_persica_var._platycarpa)*. En todos los lugares donde he consultado dice que proviene de una [mutación del melocotón común proveniente de China](http://www.frutasesther.es/ES/productos/Ficha.aspx?idf=paraguayo), sin relación con el Paraguay.

Es la primera vez que veo una imagen de esta fruta y no conocía en absoluto su nombre. En Argentina no consumimos gran variedad de frutas, a decir verdad, y de esta especie (nosotros decimos durazno, no melocotón) sólo hay dos variedades: el durazno común y el pelón (que no tiene pelusa), ambos bien esféricos.

Comment: Mis abuelos maternos, que eran de Tenerife (islas Canarias), también decían "duraznos" (para llamar a los "melocotones", no creo que conocieran los "paraguayos"). Pienso que precisamente porque parece ser que no tienen nada que ver con Paraguay tiene sentido la pregunta sobre la etimología.